# Comunicación y States entre componentes ANGULAR 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Esta claro que la comunicación entre Componentes Padres <--> Hijos se realiza mediante @Input / @Output pero para comunicar dos o mas componentes que no tienen esta relación es correcto utilizar un servicio donde se guarde la var. con el state del componente. 
Es esto correcto? 
Como se realiza según el siguiente ejemplo?

---

> [Este componente pertenece al modulo 1]

```
<component-1 state="1"></component-1>
```

---

> [Este componente pertenece al modulo 2]

```
<component-2 (click)="cambiarState(0)"></component-1>
```

> ServicioComunicación.service.ts

```
Component-1{
 - State="X"
}
```

Es como si tuviéramos una representación en Json de los estados de los componentes por el cual podríamos modificar con un servicio.

Que pensáis sobre esto??

Comment: Redux justo hace eso elevado a la máxima expresión: https://github.com/angular-redux/store

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: Es una opción pero si necesitas esa variable en otro servicio el cual ya esta inyectado el anterior. Tendras un error de dependencias circulares.

Answer (score 3):

La idea es usas el servico, lo inyectas en ambos componentes, en el component-1 te subscribers a un observable y en el component-2 cambias ese observable.

Justo despues de cambiar ese observable, tendras un trigger en el component-1 donde te habias subscrito a el, y asi habilitas la comunicacion entre ambos.

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service