# Angular pasar variables entre componentes sin herencia

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Tengo un componente NavBar con un dropdown y otro componente que mostrará un contenido dependiendo de lo seleccionado en ese dropdown.

El problema es que no sé cómo pasar ese selected desde el componente NavBar al componente que muestra.

He visto esta pregunta: [Comunicación y States entre componentes ANGULAR 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50952/comunicaci%C3%B3n-y-states-entre-componentes-angular-2) la cual dice de hacer un servicio con el cual me suscribo al navbar desde el mostrador y en el navbar cambio el observable.
También el usuario @KarlosCode comenta: "Redux justo hace eso elevado a la máxima expresión".

¿Cómo sería ese servicio? ¿Recomendáis Redux? de ser así, ¿conocéis de algún ejemplo para este caso?

Answer (score 1):

Si en tu componente principal, llamémoslo **Componente SHELL** está tu **Componente NAVBAR** y tu **Componente CONTENIDO** y tu *componente navbar* no maneja rutas sino datos puedes hacer que al hacer click en algún ítem del dropdown este guarde el dato del listado de datos que estás manejando en una variable de tu *componente navbar*, llamémoslo **datoSeleccionado**, entonces ya sólo debes de tener en tu *componente contenido* una variable de entrada con el decorador `@Input` que recibirá este *datoSeleccionado* al detectar un nuevo cambio y hará lo que tenga que hacer.

> HTML representativo

```
<app-shell-component>
  <app-navbar-component>
    <ul>
      <li *nfFor="let dato of datos" (click)="datoSeleccionado = dato">
        {{ dato | json }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <app-contenido-component [dato]="datoSeleccionado"></app-contenido-component>
  </app-navbar-component>
</app-shell-component>
```

> Componente CONTENIDO

```
@Component()
export class ContenidoComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() dato = null;

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes['dato']) {
      // Aquí ya sabes que has recibido un nuevo dato desde cualquier componente.
      const nuevoDato = changes.dato;
    }
  }

}
```